# Очень медленно грузится файл с ftp сервера c#

Tags: c#, ftp

Использую FluentFTP, скачиваю архив весом 60 мб, а он качает по 100 кб/с....

```
var token = new CancellationToken();
using (var ftp = new FtpClient("тут", "что-то", "написано"))
{
    await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

    String[] files = new String[1];

    Progress<FtpProgress> progress = new Progress<FtpProgress>(loadedFile => {

        // When progress in unknown, -1 will be sent
        if (loadedFile.Progress < 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text+" / "+Convert.ToString(loadedFile.Progress);
            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(loadedFile.Progress);
        }
    });



    //.TransferChunkSize

    // download many files, skip if they already exist on disk
    await ftp.DownloadFilesAsync(@"C:\test\",
        new[] {
            @"/public_html/index.html",
            @"/public_html/image.jpg",
            @"/public_html/archive.zip"
        }, FtpLocalExists.Skip, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, FtpError.Stop, token, progress);

}
```

Вот код

Comment: А если через браузер качать, он быстро качается?

Comment: В пассивном режиме или активном качаете? Браузер качает в пассивном.

Comment: я не знаю в пассивном или активном качаю на самом деле) Новичок в этом